# How do I address path to my layouts correctly to my 11ty (Eleventy) blogs directory built with HTML, EJS & Markdown?

Tags: javascript, ejs, static-site, eleventy, static-site-generation

I am trying to address my paths to the assets (css & img) folders but it errors out or doesn't find the paths totally in my markdown files and base.ejs files...

Please help me out guys, I know it's an issue with my config or something I don't know well...

Github repo: https://github.com/MikeTeddyOmondi/crypto-blogs

Answer (score 4):

### The issue:

`assets/` not accessible form posts inside .src/blogs/ (eg. .src/blogs/blockchain-technology.md)

### TL;DR

You need `../../assets/` instead of `../assets/`

in the template used by posts inside blogs/ folder.

### Explanation

This is the structure of your project:

```sh
➜  crypto-blogs-master tree -aI 'node_*' -L 3
.
├── .eleventy.js
├── ...
└── src
    ├── assets
    │   ├── css
    │   └── img
    ├── blogs
    │   ├── blockchain-technology.md
    │   ├── blogs.json
    │   └── ...
    ├── _includes
    │   └── base.ejs
    ├── blogs.md
    ├── index.md
    ├── projects.md
    ├── ...
```

When trying to access assets resources from blogs/index.html or projects/index.html it works as expected. because , in **base.ejs**, you have :

```html
    <link href="../assets/css/..." /> <!-- line 16 -->
    <img src="../assets/img/... " /> <!-- line 24 -->
```

But it doesn't work for the posts inside blogs/ folder.

To fix the issue, you need to change the path to the assets

```sh
  # from
  ../asstes/
  # to
  ../../asstes/
```

To do so, you can:

1. define a variable `relative_path` in the Front Matter of your template base.ejs.

```yaml
---
relative_path: '..'
---
// base.ejs
```

2. replace all the occurrences of : `../assets/`

   with: `<%= relative_path %>/assets/` in `base.ejs`
3. for each file (post) inside blog folder, you need to redefine `relative_path`,

either:

3.1. on their respective Front Matter :

```yaml
---
  relative_path: '../..'
---
// blockchain-technology.md + ... post-n.md
```

3.2. or using [eleventyComputed](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-computed/), for all of them at once, by creating a file **blogs.11tydata.js** inside blogs folder, that has this code

```js
  module.exports = function () {
    return {
      eleventyComputed: {
        relative_path: "../.."
      }
    }
  }
```

**Note 1** defining `relative_path` in /blogs/blogs.json will not work. because of the [merging order](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-cascade/#sources-of-data) of cascading data in 11ty (as of the current version).

**Note 2** the correct `relative_path` for index.md is "." instead of "..", but since it is in the input directory, it's fine.

**Note 3** A quicker solution is to duplicate base.ejs, rename it (eg. post.ejs), edit it, and call from blog.json.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I always look at the output directory when things aren't working right. I downloaded your zip, ran `eleventy` to output the build, and I see your assets correctly copied. So for example, in `public`, I see an `assets/css` directory with `styles.css` in it. In your HTML, you would link to: `/assets/css/styles.css`. Did you try that?